How to do georeferencing for mesh files
I have an OBJ file of a bridge created using Metashape. The mesh data is currently described in model coordinate (x,y,z), without any units or geographic reference (such as scale or georeferencing). I would like to convert these model coordinates into real-world geographic coordinates (longitude, latitude, and elevation). Specifically, what steps or calculations are required to map the vertex information in the OBJ file to geographic coordinates?
If there are any prerequisites or necessary conditions, please include those as well.
Specifically, what steps or calculations are required to map the vertex information in the OBJ file to geographic coordinates?
If there are any prerequisites or necessary conditions, please include those as well.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
